# C# - getting out of using with return doesnt work

Tags: c#, .net, return, task-parallel-library, using

This method works:

```
HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await GetResponseMessage(pathWithParams: $"https://api.webasd.com/crm/v3565/objects/contacts?&limit=100&after={afterValue}&archived=false");

private Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetResponseMessage(string pathWithParams = null, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = null)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var bearerToken = _configuration["BEARER_TOKEN"];
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearerToken);
 
    if (pathWithParams != null)
    {
        return httpClient.GetAsync(pathWithParams);
    } 

    return httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
}
```

But when I use "using" as shown here:

```
HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await GetResponseMessage(pathWithParams: $"https://api.webasd.com/crm/v3565/objects/contacts?&limit=100&after={afterValue}&archived=false");

private Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetResponseMessage(string pathWithParams = null, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = null)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var bearerToken = _configuration["BEARER_TOKEN"];
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearerToken);

        if (pathWithParams != null)
        {
            return httpClient.GetAsync(pathWithParams);
        } 

        return httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was
> canceled. at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host,
> Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask,
> HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean
> disposeCts) at
> KLV.IdentityServer.Core.Services.ContactService.GetAllContacts() in
> C:\Users\mk\Documents\project\sso\KLV.IdentityServer.Core\Services\ContactService.cs:line
> 309 at
> KLV.IdentityServer.Controller.ApiController.ContactsController.GetListOfContacts()
> in
> C:\Users\mk\Documents\project\sso\KLV.IdentityServer\Controller\ApiController\ContactsController.cs:line
> 64 at lambda_method(Closure , Object ) at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
> mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
> arguments) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed
> context) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
> context) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker
> invoker) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context) at
> IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService
> events) at
> IdentityServer4.Hosting.MutualTlsTokenEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context) at
> IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context) at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

I want to use `using`, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Why do you re-create the HttpClient everytime someone calls your method?

Comment: @PeterCsala using does dispose it right?

Comment: You should not recreate and dispose by yourself. You should prefer IHttpClientFactory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `await` inside `GetResponseMessage`:

```
private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetResponseMessage(string pathWithParams = null, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = null)
{
  using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
  {

    var bearerToken = _configuration["BEARER_TOKEN"];
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearerToken);

    if (pathWithParams != null){
      return await httpClient.GetAsync(pathWithParams);
    } 
      return await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
    }
  }
}
```

For more information, see my [article on eliding async/await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).

Comment: Thank you for the very fast rescue! it works... this means I shall remove the await on assignemnt? HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = GetResponseMessage()? I can accept the answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: No; in general, you should use `await` whenever you call a task-returning method. So you should use `await` for both `SendAsync` and `GetResponseMessage`.